# C++ unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

I have a class setup and from that class I am using inheritance.

In file a.h

```
class a
{
public:
    virtual void print();
};
```

In file b.h:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>
class b: public a
{
public:
    void print();
};
```

And in b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
void b::print(){};
```

In the main file I am including both of these files:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

Yet I get an unresolved symbol for the virtual function print. The file a.obj is listed as the file generating the error What am I doing wrong? If I move b.cpp into b.h below the class definition it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an implementation for b::print but not for a::print. What would happen if instantiated an object of class a and called print() on it? i.e.

```
a o;
o.print();
```

b::print overrides a::print but you still need to have an implementation of a::print (unless you make it pure virtual).

to make print pure virtual in a, define it like this:

```
virtual void print() = 0;
```

When a class has pure virtual functions, you cannot instantiate objects of that class. You must derive from that class and provide an implementation of any pure virtual functions before you have a class that can actually be instantiated.

Comment: My guess this is it even though the OP didn't really provide enough info to be sure.

Comment: Ah I got it. I had to add = 0 to the end of the virtual declarations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2 for future viewers. Thank you.

Comment: pure virtual means it has no implementation, represented by `virtual void print() = 0;` in your `class a`.

Comment: ... and most be implemented in inheriting concrete classes to match specific design patterns such as factory method

Comment: @Mark - usually, but not always.  In C++ they can have implementations too.  Derived classes are still required to provide overrides.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a typo, but in `b.cpp` you have implemented the `print()` function inside a class called `Add` rather than the `b` class.

Comment: Thank you for noting, it was a typo. (typo entering into SO, real problem still same)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a semi colon at the end of class interface